# Functions vs methods in Scala

Tags: scala

I am watching [Runar Bjarnason present Functional Programming for Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAtPi23nLcw), and at 14:45 he defines a method:

```
def isDivisibleBy(k: Int): Int => Boolean = i => i % k == 0
```

and a function:

```
val isEven = isDivisibleBy(2)
```

What are the pros and cons of defining `isEven` as a function rather than a method?

I have read [Scala Functions vs Methods](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/05/scala-functions-vs-methods.html) as well as [Difference between method and function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala), and I understand the semantic differences, but I wonder if there's some deeper reason in this case why a function might or might not be preferable to using a method:

```
def isEven = isDivisibleBy(2)
```

Comment: Just think of it in the equivalent Java (the Scala Functions vs. Methods does a good job of that) and how it fits into the run-time. That is a good bit of the reason for one approach over the other. Also note that scope of `def` is important as it's not the same everywhere (it's only a "method" -- implementation details aside -- at the class-level).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Under the hood, there are other differences between functions and methods. Generally, a plain method generated less overhead than a function (which technically is an object with an `apply` method).

However, if you try not to care about those differences and think of `def`, `val` and `var` as *fields* with different semantics, then it’s simply that `def` evaluates every time it gets called while `val` evaluates only once.

So, a `val isEven = isDivisibleBy(2)` should call `isDivisibleBy(2)` during its definition and assign the result of `isDivisibleBy(2)`. E.g. it replaces the `k` in

```
def isDivisibleBy(k: Int): Int => Boolean = i => i % k == 0
```

with `2` and assigns the result of the final expression (in this case there is only one expression):

```
val isEven: Int => Boolean = i => i % 2 == 0
```

`def isEven` on the other hand does no such evaluation and results in a call to isDivisibleBy(2) every time.

That means, later, when you execute the code, `isEven(11)` generates in case of a `val`

```
11 % 2 == 0
```

and in case of a `def`, you’ll have

```
isDivisibleBy(2)(11)
```

and only after evaluating `isDivisibleBy` you’ll get the result.

You can add some debug code to `isDivisibleBy` to see the difference:

```
def isDivisibleBy(k: Int): Int => Boolean = {
  println("evaluating isDivisibleBy")
  i => i % k == 0
}
```

Comment: What about the difference between `def` at the class-level and vs `def` inside a method? +1 as this is a nice answer (although every-time a function is applied -- e.g. in a `val` it will be called -- it's just a detail that methods can be invoked without explicit parens), but it would be nice to capture those differences (and the meaning of "method") as well.

Comment: dumb question: what does the `Boolean = ` do there ? I am new to Scala. :)

Comment: Does this mean the calling the isEven function will be faster can calling the isEven method? This is the advantage of functions over methods?

Comment: "Function" is a proxy calling methods of an anonymous class; it is workaround since JVM doesn't support pure functions. JVM has native support for classes and methods and doesn't have any idea of "functions"; implementation may differ in the future in other than JVM environments. "def" may contain other "def" in the method implementation; at runtime (bytecode-level), it is the same JVM method (not a function) with very limited scope; you can compile Scala class into Java bytecode, and  decompile into standard Java to find out "function vs. "def inside def". What about Scala.js?

Answer (score 23):

I'd like to address another point here. This defines `isEven` as a method:

```
def isEven = isDivisibleBy(2)
```

And this defines `isEven` as a method as well:

```
val isEven = isDivisibleBy(2)
```

In both cases, `isEven` is a method which, when called, return a function.

In the first case, `isDivisible(2)` is called every time `isEven` is called.  For example, this calls `isDivisible(2)` three times:

```
def isEven = isDivisibleBy(2)
List(1,2,3).filter(isEven)
```

In the second case, `isDivisible(2)` is called once (at construction time, or when that line in a definition is executed), and that value is retrieved every time `isEven` is called. The following example calls `isDivisible(2)` one time only:

```
val isEven = isDivisibleBy(2)
List(1,2,3).filter(isEven)
```

Comment: As far as I know, `val` does not define a method.  Maybe you mean it's translated to a method in java byte code for some reason (although I don't see why that would be the case).  I would think that it is simply a reference to the function object.  After all you can just pass the reference around as with other objects.

Answer (score 7):

I think that the main pro of defining the function `isEven` as `val` is to show to audience that the function can be defined this way. Then it's clear, that a function is just an object like everything else in scala. But in the world of non-demonstrating programming, there's no need to write functions as `val`s.

Comment: It's not a function definition there but an application of a method with a function result: it shows that a function (Int => Boolean) can be stored/treated as a normal object. `val square = (x) => x * x` would be a definition, which also shows the same thing. The subtle nuances between the two (**methods which are object-bound and allow overloading and overriding** (in Java terms) and **functions that are not methods**) are where it becomes "interesting".

Comment: I have vague understanding of what `function definition` is, because it's pretty hard to google :-), so I'm using it in an intuitive way. How is `val square...` different? It also accepts an argument and creates a function that is returning an object by applying `*` method to `x`. I tried to read the question thoroughly and answer this particular question. "in this case" is crucial, the question is mentioning a man talking at presentation and his point was imho to show different way of "treating" methods/functions, the question wasn't about nuances between method and functional object.

Comment: A method if an artifact of Java (perhaps Scala would have them if not a part of Java) -- objects have *methods* (these are defined with `def` in the class-level). Functions in Scala are just a special form of an object (see FunctionN, etc) that have an `apply` method (`def` inside a function are *not methods* -- actually, they can be/are implemented as such, but that's an implementation detail as this is not exposed). Scala just makes turning a *method* into a *function* (or storing a *function* in a variable) trivial. I have not seen this distinction addressed in any answer.

Comment: @coubeatczeach In the form of the function definition (`val f = (x) => x`) a new function object is explicitly created (`(x) => x`) and assigned (even if the variable is not re-assignable). The the `def` form (inside a function this is **not a method** -- implementation details aside) does NOT imply creation of an explicit function object (and in current implementations it does not, see the accepted answer).

Comment: @coubeatczeach I say all this because the question refers to `def` as being a method and does not specify a scope. Just trying to add a note (that has grown out of hand) on the question. Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

The method `def isDivisibleBy(k: Int): Int => Boolean` returns a function which takes an Int (`i`) as parameter and returns a Boolean (`i % k == 0`).

`val isEven = isDivisibleBy(2)` on the other hand is a field into which the function returned by `isDivisibleBy(2)` is stored. If you use `def` instead of `val` then the isDivisibleBy method would be called every time the isEven method is called, but now it's called only once and the result is stored in the field.

You could achieve the same result by writing `def isEven(i: Int): Boolean = i % 2 == 0`

I think the point of the example is that you can have functions which return other functions, and you can store the functions as objects, and then call them as if they were traditionally defined methods. The above code is also quite similar to [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), so that might also be one thing demonstrated by the example (although it doesn't use [Scala's syntax for currying](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/135)).

Comment: With currying it seems to get a bit slower, don’t know why.