# Passing functions and operating on their results within Scala's Actors

Tags: function, generics, scala, parameters, actor

I'm implementing an actor-based app in scala and I'm trying to be able to pass functions between the actors for them to be processed only when some message is received by the actor.

```
import actors.Actor
import java.util.Random

import scala.Numeric._
import Implicits._

class Constant(val n:Number) extends Actor{
    def act(){
        loop{
            receive{
                case "value" => reply( {n} )
            }
        }
    }
}

class Arithmetic[T: Numeric](A: ()=>T, B: ()=>T) extends Actor{
  def act(){
    receive{
      case "sum" => reply ( A() + B() )

    /*  case "mul" => reply ( A * B )
    */
    }
  }
}

object Main extends App{
    val c5 = new Constant(5)
    c5.start


    val a = new Arithmetic({c5 !! "value"}, {c5!!"value"} )
  a.start

  println(a!?"sum")
  println(a!?"mul")

}
```

In the example code above I would expect the output to be both 5+5 and 5*5. The issue is that reply is not a typed function and as such I'm unable to have the operator (+,*) to operate over the result from A and B.

Can you provide any help on how to better design/implement such system?

**Edit:** Code updated to better reflect the problem. Error in:
error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Numeric[Any]
val a = new Arithmetic({c5 !! "value"}, {c5!!"value"} )

I need to be able to pass the function to be evaluated in the actor whenever I call it. This example uses static values but I'll bu using dynamic values in the future, so, passing the value won't solve the problem. Also, I would like to receive different var types (Int/Long/Double) and still be able to use the same code.

Answer (score 1):

The error: `Error in: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Numeric[Any]`. The definition of `!!`:

```
def !! (msg: Any): Future[Any]
```

So the `T` that `Arithmetic` is getting is `Any`. There truly isn't a `Numeric[Any]`.

Comment: I understand the error. I don't understand how I can refactor the code so that I'm able to do what I want to. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: @tiagoboldt Well, first of all, `Numeric` has to be passed all along the chain -- meaning `Constant` has to receive it, and pass it on the reply. Next, once you get it back from `Constant`, you'll need to pass it to `Arithmetic`, and there's the slight matter of ensuring it is the same `Numeric` for both parameters. So, in short, give up `!!` and write code in terms of actors messaging each other.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that is *not* your problem. First, `A` and `B` are functions, and functions don't have `+` or `*`. If you called `A()` and `B()`, then you might stand a chance... except for the fact that they are `java.lang.Number`, which *also* does not have `+` or `*` (or any other method you'd expect it to have).

Basically, there's no "Number" type that is a superclass or interface of all numbers for the simple reason that Java doesn't have it. There's a lot of questions touching this subject on Stack Overflow, including some of my own very first questions about Scala -- investigate `scala.math.Numeric`, which is the best approximation for the moment.

### [Method vs Function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4839537/53013) and lack of parenthesis

Methods and functions are different things -- see tons of related questions here, and the rule regarding dropping parenthesis is different as well. I'll let REPL speak for me:

```
scala> def f: () => Int = () => 5
f: () => Int

scala> def g(): Int = 5
g: ()Int

scala> f
res2: () => Int = <function0>

scala> f()
res3: Int = 5

scala> g
res4: Int = 5

scala> g()
res5: Int = 5
```

Comment: Hi, 1st, when calling a function in scala, there's no need to use the () if there are no parameters, so, writing A is evaluated and typed to what A() would be. I've also already tried using numeric but had no luck with it. Any code/design refactor to hint on the problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: @tiagoboldt When calling a *method* there is no such need. When calling a function, there is.

Comment: I've edited my question to make it clearer. You're right on the above, but that's not my question. Hope It's clearer now.