# def or val for defining Function in Scala

Tags: function, scala, functional-programming

I'm learning Programming Paradigms in my University and reading this course material provided by the lecturer that defined a function this way:

```
val double = (x: Int) => 2 * x
double: Int => Int = <function1>
```

But from my own studies I found and got used to defining the same function like this:

```
def d (x: Int) = 2 * x
d: (x: Int)Int
```

I'm new to Scala. And both definitions give a result of:

```
res21: Int = 8
```

Upon passing `4` as the parameter. 
Now my main question is why would the lecturer prefer to use `val` to define a function? I see it as longer and not really necessary unless using `val` gives some added advantages that I don't know of. Besides I understand using `val` makes some name a placeholder so later in the program, I could mistakenly write `val double = 5` and the function would be gone!
At this stage I'm quite convinced I learned a better way of defining a function unless someone would tell me otherwise.

Comment: I'm not qualified to say something definitive about Scala, but have you tried to actually do `val double = 5` after the function is defined as `double`? I've got the impression it should be impossible to redefine a name once it is defined. In any case, both `val` and `def` produce the same result here. The difference is merely stylistic. Often, it is more clear to define a function with `def` but sometimes it makes sense to define it with `val`. If you are unsure, I would recommend you go with `def` since it is less likely to cause any confusion.

Comment: Yes, I did `val double = 5`, typed `double` and got `res24: Int = 5`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between method and function in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala)

Comment: Also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839537/functions-vs-methods-in-scala). Most of the time, you can use both variants, so it's a stylistic question. I would agree with you to prefer methods, but it's just a preference.

Comment: "`val` makes some name a placeholder"—that doesn't matter, `def d` also introduces a symbol `d` which you could latter shadow by redefining it. In that respect, there is no real difference between the two.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Strictly speaking `def d (x: Int) = 2 * x` is a method, not a Function, however scala can transparently convert (lift) methods into Functions for us. So that means you can use the `d` method anywhere that requires a `Int => Int` Function.

There is a small overhead of performing this conversion, as a new Function instance is created every time. We can see this happening here:

```
val double = (x: Int) => 2 * x
def d (x: Int) = 2 * x

def printFunc(f: Int => Int) = println(f.hashCode())

printFunc(double)
printFunc(double)
printFunc(d)
printFunc(d)
```

Which results in output like so:

```
1477986427
1477986427
574533740
1102091268
```

You can see when explicitly defining a Function using a `val`, our program only creates a single Function and reuses it when we pass as an argument to `printFunc` (we see the same hash code). When we use a `def`, the conversion to a Function happens every time we pass it to `printFunc` and we create several instances of the Function with different hash codes. [Try it](http://www.scalakata.com/526bcc03e4b0b1a1c4dae134)

That said, the performance overhead is small and often doesn't make any real difference to our program, so `def`s are often used to define Functions as many people find them more concise and easier to read.

Comment: [Some guy](http://japgolly.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/scala-methods-vs-functions.html) ran a benchmark just recently, showing that "eta-expansion" (lift a method to a function when passing it as an argument) doesn't really incur a performance penalty.

Comment: Nice post. I guess there could also be an increase in garbage collection, but I imagine that will be a tiny/non-existent too.

Answer (score 5):

In Scala, function values are monomorphic (i.e. they can not have type parameters, aka "generics"). If you want a polymorphic function, you have to work around this, for example by defining it using a method:

```
def headOption[A]: List[A] => Option[A] = {
  case Nil   => None
  case x::xs => Some(x)
}
```

It would not be valid syntax to write `val headOption[A]`. Note that this didn't make a polymorphic function value, it is just a polymorphic method, returning a monomorphic function value of the appropriate type.

Comment: What A refer to? I some time saw  **def name[T]()** i don't understand what it is[]() in scala mean

Answer (score 0):

Because you might have something like the following:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
  val intToIntFunc: Int => Int
}

class A extends BaseClass {
  override val intToIntFunc = (i: Int) => i * 2
}
```

So its purpose might not be obvious with a very simple example. But that Function value could itself be passed to higher order functions: functions that take functions as parameters. If you look in the Scala collections documentation you will see numerous methods that take functions as parameters. Its a very powerful and versatile tool, but you need to get to a certain complexity and familiarity with algorithms before the cost /benefit becomes obvious.

I would also suggest not using "double" as an identifier name. Although legal Scala, it is easy to confuse it with the type Double.