# Function Literal referencing by val and def

Tags: scala, function-literal

I'm trying to understand the crucial difference between these two approaches of referencing / defining `Function Literal` (reference to `anonymous function`):

By `val`

```
scala> val v2 = new Function[Int, Int] {
     | def apply(a: Int): Int = a + 1
     | }
v2: Int => Int = <function1>
```

And by `def`

```
scala> def f2 = new Function[Int, Int] {
     | def apply(a: Int): Int = a + 1
     | }
f2: Int => Int
```

It seems that it pretty much the same in terms of use. I either can pass `v2` or `f2` to the function that accepts `(Int) => Int` as an argument. Passing arguments to its..

I guess or the case of v2 it creates an `Function1` object that refers to the `Function1` object.. like a `proxy`?

Ok.. My question is: **what is advantage and disadvantages of 1th and 2nd approach?**

And of it is defined by `def`, is it still `Function Literal`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/18887341/985949

Comment: See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607485/def-or-val-for-defining-function-in-scala?rq=1. Basically it's a method (def) vs function object (val), but both are almost the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, neither of your examples are actually function *literals*—you're creating a `Function` instance in the plain old sugar-free way, and in fact you could use this approach (`new Function { ... }`) to create an instance of `scala.Function` from Java code.

The following are both function literals, and are exactly equivalent to your definitions:

```
val v2 = (a: Int) => a + 1
def f2 = (a: Int) => a + 1
```

The only real difference here is that the `val` will create a single instance once and for all, no matter how many times you use `v2` (and even if you never use it), while the `def` will create a new instance every time (or not at all, if you never use it). So you'll generally want to go with a `val`.

There are cases, however, where you need to use `def`. Consider the following:

```
def myIdentity[A] = (a: A) => a
```

There's no way we could write this as a `val`, since Scala doesn't have polymorphic functions in this sense (for any instance of `Function[A, B]`, `A` and `B` have to be concrete types). But we can define a polymorphic method that returns a function, and when we write e.g. `myIndentity(1)`, the `A` will be inferred to be `Int`, and we'll create (and apply) a `Function[Int, Int]` exactly as you'd expect.

Comment: if they are are exactly equivalent to my definitions and since it is syntax sugar they are supposed to be function literals (?). First I came up with your simple examples - results/outputs seems the same.

Comment: The term _literal_ in this context refers specifically to the syntax, so you'd call the sugared version a function literal, but not the plain old instantiation via `new`.

Comment: @ses `4` and `(2+2)` are exactly equivalent, but the first is an integer literal and the second is not. Same here.