# Extending FunctionN for a trait implementation

Tags: scala

I'm trying to build myself a tiny mocking library to deal with quite obvious cases:

1. Mock functions and record calls to them.
2. Mock trait implementations and be able to record calls on the methods implemented.

The first I achieved with the following implementation:

```
class LoggedFunction1[A1, B](body: A1 => B) extends Function1[A1, B] {
    val calls = mutable.Buffer[A1]()

    override def apply(v1: A1): B = {
        calls += v1
        body(v1)
    }
}

object LoggedFunction {
    def apply[A1, B](body: A1 => B) = new LoggedFunction1(body)
}
```

So far, so good.

I was now wondering if I could use this FunctionN extension somehow to implement the methods of a trait, such as:

```
trait A {
    def m(i: Int)
}

class B extends A {
    override def m(i: Int) = LoggedFunction((a: Int) => a)
}
```

Now that of course doesn't compile, because `m`'s return value must be of type `Int` and not `Function1[Int, Int]`.

I could declare a companion value to contain my information, such as:

```
class C extends A {
    val _m = LoggedFunction((a: Int) => a)
    override def m(i: Int) = _m(i)
}
```

But meh. What I really would like to do is:

```
class D extends A {
    override val m = LoggedFunction((a: Int) => a)
}
```

In my mind the latest "should" somehow work, as I'm overriding a `Function1[Int, Int]` with a `Function1[Int, Int]`, but it complains about me not overriding anything with `m`.

Is there any possibility I can override `m` using my `LoggedFunction` so I end up writing:

```
val test = new E
test.m(1)
test.m.calls should have size 1
```

If not: Why is it not possibly to override the method with a value containing a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my mind the latest "should" somehow work, as I'm overriding a `Function1[Int, Int]` with a `Function1[Int, Int]`

Overriding a method with a function this way won't work, the two are really different things. See [Functions vs methods in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839537/functions-vs-methods-in-scala).

In your precise use case, you could try the following:

```
override def m(i: Int) = LoggedFunction((a: Int) => a).apply(i)
```

Comment: I guess you meant: `apply(i)`. That works, yes, but you have no way to reach the `calls` member afterwards for introspection as you're back down to a usual function.

Comment: Store your `LoggedFunction` in a public val like you suggested, that's the only way!